# How toggle by object/by layer in 3ds Max with maxscript?

Tags: properties, maxscript

I'm looking for the function to toggle an object's "By Object"/"By Layer" property in Display Properties, specifically to "By Object".  I haven't been able to get any of the functions here http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2015/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_78B79975_7BA5_4A03_8FEF_27E78D14B575_htm to do what I want.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use next one for selection

```
mapped fn Display_ByObject_ByLayer nodes state: =
(
    if isValidNode nodes do node.displaybylayer = state
)
--now you can test it
if selection.count > 0 do Display_ByObject_ByLayer (selection as array) state:off
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help

```
fn Display_ByObject_ByLayer node state: =
(
    if isValidNode node do node.displaybylayer = state
)
-- define first some object
cube = Box()
--try to display by object
Display_ByObject_ByLayer cube state:on
--try to display by layer
Display_ByObject_ByLayer cube state:off
```